# Laravel Dotenv on beanstalkd Queue

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5.1, beanstalkd

I have three dot env, default `.env` for `example.com`, `.env.sub1` for `sub1.example.com` and `.env.queue2` for `sub2.example.com`

I am able to load different .env when I bootstrap using the following code in `bootstrap/app.php`.  This works really well when I access the websites.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {
    $environmentPath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $environmentFile = null;
    switch (getenv('HTTP_HOST')) {
        case 'sub1.example.com':
            $environmentFile = '.env.sub1';
            break;
        case 'sub2.example.com':
            $environmentFile = '.env.sub2';
            break;
    }
    if (!empty($environmentFile) && file_exists($environmentPath . $environmentFile)) {
        Dotenv::load($environmentPath, $environmentFile);
    } else {
            // .env will be in affect, do nothing
    }
});
```

This also works really well when your `QUEUE_DRIVER` is set to `sync`.

But the problem when my `QUEUE_DRIVER` is set to `beanstalkd` it take the environment variables always from `.env`.

Where is beanstalkd queue loading the `.env` while executing a queued job.

Comment: Are you running the app for queue processing from a website, or the command line? The environment variable `HTTP_HOST` doesn't exist if the script isn't run by a web-server.

Comment: I tried to hard code `Dotenv::load($environmentPath, '.env.sub1');` in app.php instead of using `HTTP_HOST` but when it runs in queue it takes the values of env from `.env` and not `.env.sub1`